# build-logic with convention plugin and global Gradle task problem

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-task, buildsrc

I migrated my project from **buildSrc** to **build-logic** with conversion plugins. All plugins work good but I also have a Gradle task that downloads localizations from 3rd party service and stores its to the res/values folder from different modules.
The problem is that this task is registered in the root of the project (room build.gradle.kts) but its class is not visible from the build-logic directory. I tried to move it to different places but it did not help.
How can I make it visible or register it as a conversion plugin but for the root project, not submodules?

Update: build-logic is a folder that  defines project-specific convention plugins. As an example I use the nowinandroid app
https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/tree/main/build-logic

Comment: What is `build-logic`? An included build? Why can't you move your class to the `build-logic` directory? Because it is also used by the main program?

Comment: build-logic is a folder that defines project-specific convention plugins. As an example, I use the nowinandroid app 
https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/tree/main/build-logic.
I moved it but then it does not visible from root build.gradle.kts. As I understand the conversion plugin includes common rules for each module and prevents its duplication but I have to get a grade task for the whole application.

Comment: Ok great: you have an included build. Well you can move your task and its class into `build-logic`, register that task inside a new plugin written in `build-logic`, publish the plugin like your other plugins in `build-logic`, then apply the new plugin in your root `build.gradle`